# Python function in separate file: they all require the same parameters. How to make global variable in multiple file?

Tags: python

My question is the following:

I have a script which requires around 10 input variables to run. Those variables are required in many of the functions I use. They are defined in the main file of my script.

Currently, all the functions I need are coded in my main file. Thus, I don't need to add in those functions extra parameters corresponding to those variables (because python functions can read "global" variable from a same file). But I would like to make my program cleaner by putting those functions in separate files. The issue with that is that all the functions would require in their definition those 10 input variables as parameters, which would be a big mess in the code.

How can I code this efficiently ? Again: I have about 10 variables in my script that I might change manually for each run. If I want to have my functions in separate files I would need to add 10 parameters to each of the functions. How to avoid that and to make my code clean ? My 10 variables are main parameters of my script and I want them to be defined in my main file.

If this is not the good place on stack exchange to ask the question, please tell me on which site I should ask.

Comment: `import <file_with_global_variables>` then you can access them with `<file_with_global_variables>.<variable>`

Comment: @AChampion thank you for your answer. And would that be considered as a cleaned way to code ? With respect to my kind of issue ? Or do you see it as a dirty trick ? I know how to code but I don't know how to make clean code. My code is usually dirty.

Comment: Use of global variables is generally frowned upon. I would get you code working and then consider posting to codereview.stackexchange.com, which is a site that does code reviews.

Comment: why you are not using class and class variables, this can use by importing anywhere...