# Import function from other file doesn't work

Tags: python, import

My main.py contains:

```
import functions

a=2
b=3

print(functions.function1(2))
```

My functions.py contains:

```
import main

def function1(x):
    return x+main.a+main.b
    
def function2(x):
    return x-main.a-main.b

def function3(x):
    return x*main.a*main.b
```

When I run my main (which is in the same folder as functions.py), it returns me an error:

```
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(functions.function1(2))

AttributeError: module 'functions' has no attribute 'function1'
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I thought it is the way to import stuff ? I would like to fix it but also to understand precisely the issue.

Note: I don't want to pass a and b as parameters of the other functions for the reason, see my related question [Python function in separate file: they all require the same parameters. How to make global variable in multiple file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858699/python-function-in-separate-file-they-all-require-the-same-parameters-how-to-m?noredirect=1#comment112923620_63858699)

Comment: You cannot have mutual imports. You could pass `a` and `b` as parameters to `function1` etc.

Comment: @quamrana I actually would like to avoid to pass them as parameters. Indeed I will have a bunch of function that will require the same parameters it would be a mess thing. See my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858699/python-function-in-separate-file-they-all-require-the-same-parameters-how-to-m?noredirect=1#comment112923620_63858699

Comment: You will be better off making all your functions into methods of the same class. Then all your `a` and `b` can be attributes of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if  you do not want to give as parameters variables `a` and `b` you could create a file `my_vars.py` and put there your variables:

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

then in your functions.py you can use these variables by importing my_vars.py:

```
import my_vars


def function1(x):
    return x + my_vars.a + my_vars.b
    
def function2(x):
    return x - my_vars.a - my_vars.b

def function3(x):
    return x * my_vars.a * my_vars.b
```

then your main.py will look like:

```
import functions

print(functions.function1(2))
```

using a file only with constants is usually a good approach

to understand why your approach doesn't work you can read about [circular imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like your approach because it looks simple and indeed I feel it will make things super clean. I also asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249268/clean-code-for-many-functions-requiring-all-the-same-constants-parameters-and-w for further recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mutually import data between files.
Try changing the functions in *functions.py* to accept *a* and *b* as parameters like so:

```
def function1(x, a, b):
    return x+a+b
    
def function2(x, a, b):
    return x-a-b

def function3(x, a, b):
    return x*a*b
```

and then passing them into the function call in *main.py* like this:

```
import functions

a=2
b=3

print(functions.function1(2, a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want parameters that you don't pass as arguments you can make a class instead:

```py
#main.py
import functions

f = functions.f()
f.a=2
f.b=3

print(f.function1(2))

# functions.py
class f:
    def __init__(self):
        # default values for a and b
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3

    def function1(self, x):
        return x + self.a + self.b
```

With classes there is also the side-effect that you can have two instances at the same time, each with their own `a` and `b`:

```py
f1 = functions.f()
f1.a = 2
f1.b = 3

f2 = functions.f()
f2.a = 12
f2.b = 13

print(f1.function1(2))
print(f2.function1(2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like a clean way to do it indeed. Kederrac also proposed something interesting I think.

Comment: Please take your time to evaluate all the answers here to see what most benefits your situation.

Answer (score 1):

it's not clear about the reason, but may be it helps, if your placed variables in their own module

like this:

#### main.py

```
# main.py

import functions
import variables

# you able to use it here
# print(variables.a)

print(functions.function1(2))
```

#### functions.py

```
# functions.py
import variables

def function1(x):
    return x+variables.a+variables.b

def function2(x):
    return x-variables.a-variables.b

def function3(x):
return x*variables.a*variables.b
```

#### variables.py

```
# variables.py
a=2
b=3
```

Answer (score 0):

In functions.py you can `import main` in the bodies of the functions, avoiding in this way the circular import.

```
def function1(x):
    import main
    return x+main.a+main.b
    
def function2(x):
    import main
    return x-main.a-main.b

def function3(x):
    import main
    return x*main.a*main.b
```